# What could be reason of getting SSL connect error while posting json request to https url from Windows PC?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, libcurl, tls1.2

I am using libcurl.dll version 7.72.0.0 in Visual Studio for a C++ application.

When I am posting a JSON request to an HTTPS url on one Windows 7 PC with Service Pack 1, the request is posted successfully. But on other PC with same OS as Windows 7 Service Pack 1, I am getting response code 35 from `curl_easy_perform()`: SSL connect error.

What could be the reason of the same C++ code working on one Windows 7 PC and getting an error on other Windows 7 PC? Both PCs are on the same network.

Following is the C++ code:

```cpp
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, Url.c_str());

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
 
// send all data to this function  
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
 
// we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&sResponse);
 
//some servers don't like requests that are made without a user-agent
//  field, so we provide one
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postthis);
printf("\npostthisData=%s\n", postthis);
        
if (itsHTTPSRequest)
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

// if we don't provide POSTFIELDSIZE, libcurl will strlen() by
//   itself 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (long)strlen(postthis));

curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, m_RWTimeOut );
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, m_RWTimeOut);
curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 30L);
```

Comment: Turn on CURLOPT_VERBOSE to get more information from curl. Also note that disabling ssl  peer verification bypasses much of the security TLS provides.

Comment: Per the [`curl_easy_perform()` documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html): "*CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR (35) A problem occurred somewhere in the SSL/TLS handshake. **You really want the error buffer and read the message there as it pinpoints the problem slightly more.** Could be certificates (file formats, paths, permissions), passwords, and others.*"  See [`CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER.html)

Comment: You didn't mention what TLS backends your libcurl installs use. Which one? Are they perhaps using different ones?

Comment: @Botje Thanks for replying.

Following are verbose logs:
*   Trying 165.22.223.40:8443...
* Connected to tepscetp.in (165.22.223.40) port 8443 (#0)
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x8009
0326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. h
andshake failed). More detail may be available in the Windows System event log.
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with tepscetp.in port 8443

Curl response code = 35
curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL connect error

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Also I saw windows system event logs, No errors were logged in it. But I found below as latest log:
- EventData 
   http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab 
   A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

Comment: Check [this conversation](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/schannel-failed-to-receive-handshake-need-more-data/99400/2). If i read it correctly, that server offers a cipher one of your systems does not support. Can you check the TLS conversation with `curl - v` on a different machine (or `openssl s_client` on any machine ) ?

Comment: That was supposed to be `curl -v`, typo.

Comment: Issue was fixed on windows 7. .net software was blocking TLS. So we had to disable .net software